# Get rid of special characters such as Â when scraping

Tags: javascript, excel, encoding, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape some tables off of Confluence using javascript and make CSVs. When I open the CSV on Excel a lot of the data has special characters, and some of the fields end up looking like this:

```
 Â RÃ¼diger Fritsches
```

and I would like to get rid of the special characters. A lot of the other stack overflow answers I've been looking at suggest that this is a character encoding issue however, when I attempt to clean the text using the following code:

```
function getFixedString(string) {
  try {
     return decodeURIComponent(escape(string));
  }
  catch(e) {
    return string;
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. Are there any other approaches to this issue? I've successfully been able to get a clean file by first opening in Notepad, saving as txt, and then reopening in Excel, however this is not a solution that I can give to my client.

While this is not exactly the way my program functions, you can reproduce the error by running this program and opening the csv in Excel:

```
str = "@nbayly when done manually the outcome is Rüdiger Fritsches,The original website's charset is UTF-8.";
str = getFixedString(str);
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([str], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'}));
a.download = 'test.csv';

 // Append anchor to body.
document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click();

// Remove anchor from body
document.body.removeChild(a)

function getFixedString(string) {
  try {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(string));
  }
  catch(e) {
    return string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you do that exercise of doing it manually just so we can see what the decoding of your sample text actually should looks like? When I searched online for `RÃ¼diger` I found websites that similar encoding issue. Can you also check on the source what the encoding is originally?

Comment: @nbayly when done manually the outcome is Rüdiger Fritsches. The original website's charset is UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to remove all of the non-ascii characters.  You could do something such as the following:

```
function getFixedString(string){
     return string.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: While this does delete the poorly encoded characters it does not produce the wanted output, though it is close. (eg RÃ¼diger -> Rdiger instead of RÃ¼diger -> Rüdiger)